# Best practice to create user in greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I have created a database in Greenplum.

`CREATE DATABASE production
      WITH OWNER = gpadmin
          TEMPLATE = template1
           CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;`

I have assigned the owner to gpadmin. gpadmin is default user. What is best practice to assign the owner to any database in the Greenplum?

Answer (score 0):

gpadmin is a superuser and a good candidate for the ownership of a database.

Answer (score 0):

Some companies have a dedicated, non-superuser account which owns all objects in a database. This makes permission handling easier, because ownership of objects is not "distributed" across dozens of accounts.